# How do I process the event for a menu item click

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

i am working on WPF for building a simple word application and using RichTextBox for editing the flow content.
I ve created an instance of RichTextBox i-e RichTextBox1; i have a menu bar on which a menu item font is present and inside it are multiple font selection options i-e FontSize, FontColor, FontStyle, when they are clicked the text being entered in RTB must change accordingly. Now how can i counter this event. This all should be done at run time.
Please help me, any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: That title is one of the most useless i've seen in a while, rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

> i have a menu bar on which a menu item font is present and inside it
>   are multiple font selection options i-e FontSize, FontColor,
>   FontStyle,

You need to implement binding so the RichTextBox values for FontSize, Fontcolor, FontStyle. However, do you want the whole document to use these values or just the selected text or text from the current cursor position on?

Comment: The selected text and also the text from current cursor position